# How to split the string not use Split function?

Tags: c#

I have this parameter below

token[10] ="Date: UTC 2012-02-02 17:09:04"

i wrote the following code to extract only year and month,so it suppose to be "201202".
is this anyway i can get only those value with out using split,i know we can use regex too but is this any other way to extract those values

```
        string Encdate = tokens[10];
        string[] EncdateValue = Encdate.ToString().Split(' ');
        string Encdatesplit = EncdateValue[2].TrimStart();
        string[] YYMM = Encdatesplit.ToString().Split('-');
        string YYMMVal = YYMM[0] + YYMM[1];
```

Comment: Could do a little string manipulation, cast it to a datetime, and then do a formatted .ToString() on it

Comment: Why don't you parse the date into a DateTime object and extract the components using the DateTime functions.  Get the year and month and concatenate them to get your desired value.

Comment: @agarcian,that sounds great though.

Comment: @StefanH,thanks a lot, i will try follow your idea.

Comment: @agarcian and I are pretty much saying the same thing :)

Comment: Seems that your data is at a fixed position, so why bother with Split() or Date conversion, do a simple Substring() extraction as @keijzers suggest (after replacing `token` with `Encdate`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `DateTime.ParseExact` method and access the `Year` and `Month` properties from the returned `DateTime` object, otherwise use [Date/Time string formatters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) and the [DateTime.ToString(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) method to get the yyyyMM format, here is an example:

```
        var d = DateTime.ParseExact(token, "'Date: UTC' yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", 
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces | DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal);

        Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("yyyyMM"));
```

Answer (score 0):

var t = token[10];

You also could use a concatenation of the needed characters:

```
string Encdate = t[10] + t[11] + t[12] + t[13] + t[15] + t[16];
```

Or use substring (for adding the two):

```
string Encdate = t.Substring(10, 4) + t.Substring(15, 2);
```

Or a substring and a remove:

```
string Encdate = t.Substring(10, 7).Remove(4);
```

Comment: my token[10] value is "Date: UTC 2012-02-02 17:09:04".

Comment: In your question is stated:

    token ="Date: UTC 2012-02-02 17:09:04"

Comment: You are welcome ... however are my answers not what you are looking for? they all result in "201202".